# Literal match of strings in dataframe to other dataframe with multiple match options

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) with values in a column 'country' that I wish to standardize, using another dataframe called 'country_codes'. A value from df can match against any item from 'country_codes', but the resulting dataframe should contain the corresponding country_code['country'] value, i.e, the standard value.

The code mainly works and does indeed return the standard country value, but the regex doesn't match the exact string. It matches too little (in this case: 'Example1').

Additional question: is there a possibility of preserving the 'year' data in the final output dataframe, without specifying the name 'year', as there could be multiple float columns.

Below shows the function and desired outputs:

```
def match_country_codes(df, country_codes):
    # Create a regex pattern to match whole words
    pattern = '|'.join(rf'\b{re.escape(c)}\b' for c in country_codes[['country', 'alpha1', 'alpha2']].values.flatten())
    # new column for matches between pattern and df['country'] items
    df['matched_country'] = df['country'].str.extract(f'({pattern})', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    # Merge with 'country_codes' dataframe to get the full country names
    # merge over 3 frames for all columns
    df1 = df.merge(country_codes, left_on='matched_country', right_on='country', how='left')
    df2 = df.merge(country_codes, left_on='matched_country', right_on='alpha1', how='left')
    df3 = df.merge(country_codes, left_on='matched_country', right_on='alpha2', how='left')

    dataframes = [df1, df2, df3]
    # merge all dataframes together on '[['country_y']]'
    result = reduce(merge_dataframes, dataframes)
    # Drop rows with None or NaN values in the 'country_y' column
    result = result.dropna(subset=['country_y'])
    # return result
    return result
```

Sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['foobar', 'foo and bar', 'Example1 and', 'PQR'], 
                  'year':[2018, 2019, 'NA',2017] 
                      })
country_codes = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['FooBar', 'Example1', 'foo and bar and foo', 'Example'],
                   'alpha1': ['foobar', 'Bosnia', 'ABC', 'DEF'],
                   'alpha2': ['GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR']             
                             })
```

Output:

```
result = match_country_codes(df, country_codes)
result
```

Desired Output:

```
data = {'country_y': ['FooBar', 'Example']
           }

index_values = [0, 3]

desired_output = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index_values)
desired_output
```

Thank you

Comment: post definition of `merge_dataframes` and why `PQR` is missed in the final df?

Comment: PQR should match with 'PQR' in alpha2: then 'Example' should be returned as this is the 'standard' value from country_codes['country']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification to your approach: `join` the incoming dataframe to `country_codes` on each of the columns (using `set_index`) then take the first non-NaN value in each row's `country` values.

```py
df['country_y'] = (df
    .join(country_codes.set_index('country', drop=False), on='country', rsuffix='_1')
    .join(country_codes.set_index('alpha1'), on='country', rsuffix='_2')
    .join(country_codes.set_index('alpha2'), on='country', rsuffix='_3')
    [['country_1', 'country_2', 'country_3']]
    .groupby(lambda r: 'X', axis=1)
    .first()
)
df = df.dropna(subset='country_y')
```

For this sample data:

```
data = {
  'country': [None, 'foobar', 'foo and bar', 'Example1 and', 'PQR', 'Example', 'Bosnia', None, 'JKL', 'foobar'],
  'year': [None, None, 2018, 2019, 2017, 2020, 2017, None, 2019, 2019]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Input:

```
        country    year
0          None     NaN
1        foobar     NaN
2   foo and bar  2018.0
3  Example1 and  2019.0
4           PQR  2017.0
5       Example  2020.0
6        Bosnia  2017.0
7          None     NaN
8           JKL  2019.0
9        foobar  2019.0
```

The output will be:

```
   country    year country_y
1   foobar     NaN    FooBar
4      PQR  2017.0   Example
5  Example  2020.0   Example
6   Bosnia  2017.0  Example1
8      JKL  2019.0  Example1
9   foobar  2019.0    FooBar
```

Comment: thank you but if there are 'NA' values, the code stops working, even if they are dropped. 

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': [np.nan, np.nan, 'foobar', 'foo and bar', 'Example1 and', 'PQR'], 
                  'year':[np.nan, np.nan, 2018, 2019, 'NA',2017] 
                      })
country_codes = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['FooBar', 'Example1', 'foo and bar and foo', 'Example'],
                   'alpha1': ['foobar', 'Bosnia', 'ABC', 'DEF'],
                   'alpha2': ['GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR']             
                             })
df = df.dropna()

```

Comment: it works now: dropping na and resetting index in df['country'] to start with. thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminAllen yeah, I'm looking at it now, it's an index sorting problem arising in the `join`, which doesn't seem to be working as the docs say it should. What you suggest is definitely a workaround, but I'll still try and figure out why it is happening.

Comment: @BenjaminAllen late here, I'll take another look in the morning. I've made a note about the issue in the answer for now.

Comment: @BenjaminAllen the issue isn't so much `NaN` values as duplicate values for `country`. If you `drop_duplicates` first the code will work as expected. See my edit.

Comment: I cant drop duplicates in my project version, and some countries aren't getting match even though a merge has proved they are identical.  Any further help would be really appreciated thanks, Ben

Comment: @BenjaminAllen please see my edit. I believe I've resolved the duplicate and/or `NaN` country value issue. I also think you were losing other values because you had `NaN` values elsewhere in the data (e.g. `year`) and the `dropna` was looking at all columns; I've changed it to *only* look at `country_y`, which should resolve that issue.